# Formula or way (in excel) to count column A only if column B of the same row is the first of it's kind and column A is less then a specified value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am embarking on a new project and am curious if I am able to be selectively count a column only if another column of the same row is the first of its kind.

Situation:
column A contains people's names, which sometimes might duplicate. Column B contains amount of money spent by those people in a shop. I am only interested in people who spent less then a dollar in that shop and for those people who spent less then a dollar in the shop, their names might have duplicates but I only want to count them once, is there a excel function to do so? (eg, Mathew is a person that spends less then a dollar, his name appeared twice but I only want to count him once a.k.a count distinct)

Comment: Please add some sample data with expected results in markdown format or even a screenshot and add your own attempt at solving this.

Comment: How to cope with counting of spends over 1 Dollar, or if a person spend over 1 Dollar once and 5 times under a dollar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FILTER` function to first return a list of names that have spent under a certain amount, and then use the `UNIQUE` function to remove duplicates.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A17,B2:B17<2))
```

[image: names under $2]